# Usage of 'from' and 'since'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, time

I am often confused with the usage of *since* and *from*.

> I know him from 15 years
>
> I know him since 15 years.

Which one is correct? How would I decide which is the right preposition to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 'Since' and 'From'

'Since' talks about one particular point of time till now.

> I have been working ***since*** 7 am

'From' in *most of the cases* talks about the starting point and ending point. Said that, the format could be 'from....to/till/until'

> The shop is open ***from*** 9 in the morning ***to*** 6 in the evening

Quite close is 'since' and 'for'

### 'Since' and 'For'

Okay, as I said, 'since' talks about a particular point. So, you need to mention "since" which date the thing has been happening.

On the other hand, 'for' is used for a total period of time and you don't need to define a starting point.

The best example I can think of is...

> I have been waiting ***for*** two hours

but...

> I have been waiting ***since*** 2 o'clock

In the latter example, you need to define the starting point.

Another example:

> I have been living in this house ***for*** 10 years 
>  I have been living in this house ***since*** 2005

So, in your case, you have known him ***for*** the past 15 years OR ***since*** 2000.

Comment: Not direct to the question; but in the last sentence, you need a past tense to describe the past: "You have known him for the past 15 years," or "You have known him since the year 2000."

Comment: @Evelyn Or, if your knowledge of him is an episode from the past and not continuous, you could say *I know him from 15 years ago*.

Comment: @choster, you're quite right. That usage is almost always followed by specifics of the episode: "I know him from 15 years ago, when we spent a summer working as deckhands on the same fishing trawler."

Comment: still needs 'for **the** past 15 years' in your last para, or 'for 15 years'. 'past' has to take 'the'

Comment: @Tetsujin, buddy, you could have done it. :)

Comment: @MaulikV - for sure - but the edit would have been too small to auto-notify you & I balanced 'teaching' against 'fixing' & came out wearing my mortar-board ;-)))

Answer (score 0):

When we use ***'since'*** we generally refer to **a particular point of time or a specified time in the past**. For example - *He has been living here since 1988. She has been awake since dawn / 5'o clock. They have been working here since their youth*. So the sentence - " *I know him since 15 years* " - is wrong. The correct form is - " *I know him for 15 years* ".

In the same way ' ***from*** ' is also used to refer to **a particular point of time**, and in addition to it, it can also be used to refer to **the starting point as well as the ending point**. For example - *The world cup will start from 14th February. We lived in Oslo from 1988 to 2009*.

To refer to **a period of time** we generally use '***for***'. For example - *It has been raining in New York for three days*.