# I'm in New York since one week

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, writing

> I'm in New York with my parents and my sisters since one week.

The sentence is from a letter written by a teacher. Is "since one week" grammatical?
I'm not sure that in the sentence, the use of tense and adverbial is correct.

Comment: No. Americans, at least, do not use the construction "since one week"... It's something I only ever hear Indian English speakers say.

Comment: What are you even trying to say?

Comment: See [Usage of 'from' and 'since'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52992/usage-of-from-and-since).

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you mean a one week period of time, and you are still there, then:

> I *have been* in New York with my parents and my sisters **for one week**.

If you mean the 7 days prior to the statement, then:

> I *have been* in New York with my parents and my sisters **since one week ago**.

I prefer *have been* since you are referring to a period of time.